# How to make this kind of logo?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo

[image: I want to know how to make this effect]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIw2D.png):I want to know how to make this effect. Please help me

Comment: Are you meaning the three dotted cylinders intersected? Have you tried to start from a bunch of boxes and [distort the envelope](http://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/reshape-using-envelopes.html)? Can you tell something about your efforts?

Answer (score 2):

As Paolo mentioned before, draw your logo (three stripes of orange boxes in this case), then distort the envelope, copy, paste, rotate and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

[In this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Fh-9Ajs0ck) have described exactly the way you want.

Comment: Hi Fatih, could you please explain a bit more what we'll find behind the link you provide and why it answers the question? That way, your answer is still of value in case the link breaks at a later time. Link rot is the main reason we really dislike link-only answers here. Thanks for your effort and keep contributing!